# Unable to fit the linear multivariate regression model due to missing values in CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, linear-regression

I am trying to perform linear regression model with multiple variables. I have a CSV file with attributes: `'area', 'bedrooms', 'age', 'price'`, but bedrooms has a **missing value** (i.e. `NaN`). I want to fit the model and predict the price by giving the other three attributes, but due to one missing value I am shown the error `input contains nan infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')`. I found the median and filled in the missing value, but in the CSV file, it is not replaced and giving the error while fitting the model.
The CSV file is as follows:

[image: CSV file]

I have used the following codes:

```
df=pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\rohit\Desktop\homeprices4.csv")

df

m=math.floor(df.bedrooms.median()) // m is median which I have calculated

m

df.bedrooms.fillna(m)

reg=linear_model.LinearRegression()

reg.fit(df[['area','bedrooms','age']],df.price)
```

After this line I am getting the error because bedrooms has one missing value. If I remove `bedrooms` from this line and use only `area` and `age` for prediction then **NO** error, and I am getting correct results.

So my question is: How do I replace the missing value with the median in the CSV file? What is the code for that? 
Why I am getting the error?

Look at the screenshot for the error:

[image]

Comment: [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors), this applies to data too.

Comment: this technique is called [imputation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imputation_(statistics)) and is quite a big field.  it's easy to introduce bias into the regression if you've got a significant amount of missing data especially if it's not ["missing at random"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missing_data), and I'd expect number of bedrooms to be strongly correlated with price

Answer (score 2):

Two questions in your post:

1. Your changes are not saved to the dataframe because `fillna` would return a copy unless `inplace=True` is passed in arguments. This is why you still get the error.
2. To save the changes to CSV you need to use `DataFrame.to_csv(...)`, but given my previous point maybe you don't need this.

I would enrich your pipeline with a data cleaning step and save the cleaned data. I would do 2 separate scripts.

Data cleaning:

```
path_raw_data= r"C:\Users\rohit\Desktop\homeprices4.csv"
path_clean_data= r"C:\Users\rohit\Desktop\homeprices4_clean.csv"
df=pd.read_csv(path_raw_data)
m=math.floor(df.bedrooms.median()) // m is median which I have calculated
df.bedrooms.fillna(m, inplace=True)
df.to_csv(path_clean_data)
```

Linear regression:

```
path_clean_data= r"C:\Users\rohit\Desktop\homeprices4_clean.csv"
df=pd.read_csv(path_clean_data)
reg=linear_model.LinearRegression()
reg.fit(df[['area','bedrooms','age']],df.price)
```

Comment: Upvoted for the quality, clarity, and utility of the answer.